# Turn off Inline Expansion but let Optimization be there

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

While doing performance analysis, I have encountered a problem where some functions are not being detected since the compiler is inlining them as part of /Ox optimisation.

So the problem is :
How to use set the /Ob1 or /Ob0 switch but let the /Ox switch remain on.??? 
the Ox switch as I figure automatically turns the Ob switch to /Ob2 ??

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f8h5cxt(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Why would you like to measure non-inlined functions, if they are actually inlined in production code? You wouldn't ask Usain Bolt to *walk* 100 meters, just so he would be easier to time.

Comment: the whole problem is to identify places where performance can be improved. So when some functions are skipped ...the base function is what looks like taking a lot of time while in reality its the function that got inlined that's taking the most amount of time. Its just a way to find all such functions quickly.

Comment: The timing for a function can differ *a lot* between the inlined and non-inlined version. If you don't inline anything, the measurement might be totally wrong. I have a program where the difference is a factor of 100x, and you can't tell anything from the measurements.

Comment: @KshitijBanerjee: It doesn't make sense to talk about "the function that got inlined that's taking the most amount of time". Once a function is inlined, the optimizer will take another pass on the inlined results. That means generally some inlined operations are removed, others are mixed or changed, etc. That also means the `/Ox` flag is only half effective when you turn off inlining, so you just can't measure the full effect of `/Ox` in isolation.

Comment: The exact time measurement is not needed in my case. We only want to find the top 10 or so places where to give efforts into.So even if the measurement may be wrong it does help me in identifying where all i should spend my energy into... In my case the inlined function is THE most expensive function in the code and it has been ignored since a long while because it was never detected in performance analysis. Improving it has resulted in quite a lot of improvements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59a3b321%28v=vs.71%29.aspx /Ox is the same as:

```
/Obn, where n = 2
/Og
/Oi
/Os, /O, /Ot
/Oy
```

So I would suggest:

```
/Ob0 /Og /Oi /Os /O /Ot /Oy
```

(of course you can change /Ob0 to /Ob1 if that's what you need).